# AzDo: SSIS Build task failing to find vswhere

Tags: ssis, azure-devops

We have a self-hosted angent pool and I'm trying to run a pipeline with the "SSIS Build" task from Microsoft.

The MS Build task running on the same agents can find vswhere.exe just fine from what I see in the logs.
But the "SSIS Build" task is failing to find it for some reason.

I've not checked whether we have SSDT installed on the agents, could this cause the issue?

```
##[section]Starting: Build SSIS
==============================================================================
Task         : SSIS Build
Description  : Build single or multiple SSIS dtproj files in project deployment model or package deployment model.
Version      : 0.2.3
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://aka.ms/AA6pzmk (Check out SSIS Catalog Configuration task if you want to configure folders, projects and environments in SSIS catalog.)
==============================================================================
----------------------------------inputs---------------------------------------
projectPath: <OurPath>.dtproj
configuration: Development
outputPath: <OurOutputPath>
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Checking and standardizing arguments...
Getting devenv.exe path...
ERR:No vswhere available in this machine.
##[error]No vswhere available in this machine.
##[section]Finishing: Build SSIS
```

Comment: Hi axk, any update on this issue. Did you get a chance to implement the solution that billinkc suggested? Were you able to resolve?

Comment: Hi, it worked after SSDT was installed, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that, yes, [you need to install Visual Studio and SSIS designer for self-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/devops/ssis-devops-overview?view=sql-server-ver15#limitations-and-known-issues).

### Limitations and known issues

> - SSIS Build task relies on Visual Studio and SSIS designer, which is mandatory on build agents. Thus, to run SSIS Build task in the pipeline, you must choose vs2017-win2016 for Microsoft-hosted agents, or install Visual Studio and SSIS designer (either VS2017 + SSDT2017, or VS2019 + SSIS Projects extension) on self-hosted agents.
> - To build SSIS projects using any out-of-box components (including SSIS Azure feature pack, and other third-party components), those out-of-box components must be installed on the machine where the pipeline agent is running. For Microsoft-hosted agent, user can add a PowerShell Script task or Command Line Script task to download and install the components before SSIS Build task is executed. Below is the sample PowerShell script to install Azure Feature Pack
> - Protection level EncryptSensitiveWithPassword and EncryptAllWithPassword are not supported in SSIS Build task. Make sure all SSIS projects in codebase are not using these two protection levels, or SSIS Build task will hang and time out during execution